# Create new Tkinter Message Boxes when a button in an already existing Message Box

Tags: python, user-interface, github, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I am trying to create 2 new message boxes when the "Ok" button is pressed in an already existing message box.
This is my code

```html
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

window = Tk()
window.wm_withdraw()

#centre screen message
window.geometry("1x1+"+str(window.winfo_screenwidth()/2)+"+"+str(window.winfo_screenheight()/2))
tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Hydra", message="Cut one head off, two more will grow back.")

def onclick():
    window.geometry("1x1+"+str(window.winfo_screenwidth()/2)+"+"+str(window.winfo_screenheight()/2))
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Hydra", message="Cut one head off, two more will grow back.")
    window.geometry("1x1+"+str(window.winfo_screenwidth()/2)+"+"+str(window.winfo_screenheight()/2))
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Hydra", message="Cut one head off, two more will grow back.")
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10, so details of my answer might not be correct.

Messagebox does not accept a command parameter which means you can not use a messagebox to start anything. Also, messagebox is a modal dialog which means it will suspend the main program until it's done. This means only one message box will be displayed at any time.

I think the easiest way would be to construct a non-modal custom dialog for this problem.